# jquery validate not posting success event correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate in order to validate fields on a registration form. I use the remote method in order to call my webservice to lookup whether an email address exists.

If the email address already exists it correctly shows the "email address in use" message, however if the email does not exist, it is returning the success value (1) as an error on the page.

Here is the code I'm using:

JQUERY:

```
$("#register-form").validate({
        rules: {
                udemail: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: "/services/VerifyUserAvailability.ashx",
                        type: "post",
                        complete: function (data) {
                            if (data.responseText == "1") {
                                //alert("Free");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                ignore: ".ignore"

        },
        messages: {

             udemail: {
                 required: "Please enter your email address",
                 remote: "The email address has already been registered"
             }
        },
        onfocusout: function(element) {
            this.element(element);
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.attr("name") == "terms" ) {
                error.insertAfter("label.checkbox");
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).parent().addClass("error");
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).parent().removeClass("error");
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="" class="required email" id="EmailAddress" name="udemail">
```

I just need it to not show an error message when the returned value is 1.

Comment: when you uncomment the alert, does it show?

Comment: You need to show us the server-side function at `/services/VerifyUserAvailability.ashx`, because this is what really determines whether or not this field passes validation.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `rules` option...

```
rules: {
    udemail: {
        // rules for 'udemail' 
    },
    ignore: ".ignore"  // <- incorrect placement
},
```

**The `ignore` option does not belong *inside* of `rules`**.  Only `key:value` pairs consisting of field names and rules belong inside of `rules`.

The `ignore` option is a *sibling* of `rules`.

```
rules: {
    // your rules
},
messages: {
    // your messages
},
ignore: ".ignore",  // <- goes here as a sibling of the other options
onfocusout: function(element) { .....
```

---

You are using the `remote` method incorrectly...

```
remote: {
    url: "/services/VerifyUserAvailability.ashx",
    type: "post",
    complete: function (data) {  // <- UNNECESSARY 
        if (data.responseText == "1") {
            //alert("Free");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You do not need a `complete` callback function with a boolean inside the `remote`.  Your *server-side* function at `/services/VerifyUserAvailability.ashx` is supposed to give a "response" (`echo`, etc) of `true` if the field passes validation and `false` (or a JSON string representing the error message) if it does not.  The `true` and `false` responses are then handled automatically by the plugin.

If your server-side function is constructed properly, this is all you would need...

```
remote: {
    url: "/services/VerifyUserAvailability.ashx",
    type: "post"
}
```

http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

> The **serverside** resource is called via jQuery.ajax (XMLHttpRequest) and gets a key/value pair corresponding to the name of the validated element and its value as a GET parameter. The **response** is evaluated as JSON and must be `true` for valid elements, and can be any `false`, `undefined` or `null` for invalid elements, using the default message; or a string, eg. `"That name is already taken, try peter123 instead"` to display as the error message.

**Quote OP:**

> *"however if the email does not exist, it is returning the success value (1) as an error on the page."*

That's because it's interpreting your server response of `1` as a string instead of `true`.  Any string coming from the server-side response is considered "failed" validation and the string itself becomes the error message.  Make sure your server-side script's response is `true` for success and `false` or a JSON string for failure.